# Paying UK tax when working remote for a US company

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, employment

I'm currently employed by a US company and I'm working remotely from the UK (I'm a UK resident).

In my previous employment tax was deducted automatically from wage however tax isn't being deducted from my current US employer.

I called HMRC for advise but they weren't very helpful, telling me to send them a letter explaining the situation and couldn't assist further.

I thought it would be a simple case of filing for self assessment but on the phone HMRC didn't think self assessment would be the correct course of action.

Also I'm not on a fixed monthly wage. I get paid depending how much I decide to work from week to week, which can vary.

Any help would be appreciated so I can finally pay my taxes.

Comment: Did you write HMRC the letter they requested?

Comment: Not yet, I had a word with my old employer's accountant and he said that he will take a look at my contract first because it sounds to him like I can just file self-assessment and HMRC take weeks to reply.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, but I'm also a student. I would want to know a definite answer in order to avoid any issues with taxes.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to determine if you are self employeed. Some of the pointers can be, when you are working for the US Company what does your appointment letter / contract say? Do you submit invoice before getting paid?

If you are freelancing, then you are self employed and will have to pay tax on your own.